# prevent back to login page after user is logged in jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, servlet-filters

i am using jsp servlet to make a web application, I want to prevent the user to show login page, if he already logged in, I make a filter that check that, but it still show login page even user has a valid session, Here is the code in the Filter.

```
  HttpSession session = httpreq.getSession(false);

    if(session == null){
        System.out.println("not logged, redirect ");
          httpres.sendRedirect("../Login.jsp");

    }
    else{
            System.out.println("could be logged");
           String logged = (String) session.getAttribute("Login");
           if(logged != null){
                   System.out.println(" logged  "+logged);
               if (!logged.equals("ok")) { // user is not logged
                    System.out.println("not logged, redirect ");
                    httpres.sendRedirect("../Login.jsp");
                    return;
                } else {  // if user has a session redirect his to the page he was opened
                       System.out.println("redirect to the  same page");
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    System.out.println("redirect to the  same page");
                    httpres.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    httpres.sendRedirect(httpreq.getRequestURI());
                }
           }else
           {
                 System.out.println("not logged, redirect login ");
                    httpres.sendRedirect("../Login.jsp");
                    return;
           }

    }
```

I make the session only on folders that located outside the WEB-INF folder.

**Edit** : Here's the code to check the validity of user and add attributes to session

```
  isVaild = StudentManagement.isValidUser(connection, studentUserName, password);
               //     I have more than one roles in the system..
            }
            if (isVaild) {

                System.out.println("create session");
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("Login", "ok");
                session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
                session.setAttribute("role", role);
                if (role == UserRole.STUDENT) {  //student role
                    url = "/ParentManagementServlet?pageName=StudentActivationPage";

                    forward(request, response, url);
                } else if (role == UserRole.ADMIN) {  //admin role
                    url = "/Admin/MainPage.jsp";
                    forward(request, response, url);
                }
```

**Edit 2:**
here's the URL mapping in web.xml file

```
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

since Admin is the folder that locates outside the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: where have you written this logic?

Comment: @Alaa - Can you explain more like - when user can see the login page? 1) by hitting the login page URL again or 2) using the browser's back button

Comment: @Falcon, user shouldn't be able to go back to login in both cases u mention, this filter to prevent hinting the login page URL, and I should find the way to prevent using back button too.

Comment: @Alaa - Can you pls show the code where you set the attributes like Login ? and what the sout says.. are they showing up?

Comment: can u check the updated section please.

Comment: Everything seems fine.. I only doubt on your Filter url-pattern mapping in DD.

Comment: @Falcon, please check the url-mapping.

Comment: @Alaa - and full path (from context) of your login page- Login.jsp ?

Comment: @Falcon, the path that I type in the URL is http://localhost:8080/OnlineQuerySystemNew/Login.jsp since "OnlineQuerySystemNew" is the project name.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, apart from Filter mapping, try -

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/protected directory/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm assuming you want to protect everything in the directory and the above url pattern will check for whole directory  .. you can fine tune the pattern as per your need. 
But the point is - pattern mentioned in question (`<url-pattern>/Admin/*</url-pattern>`)  does **not** intercept `Login.jsp` and that's why it cannot perform session check and renders `Login.jsp` even for valid sessions.
You can perform a check in the existing filter - whether the request is for Login.jsp and then can make a decision (I don't know whether this is a good way to go) else keep the Login.jsp out of the protected directory and write an another filter which matches only `Login.jsp`

Comment: when I make like this"/*", Login.jsp dosn't run, it seems as it's protected too, it maps into http://localhost:8080/Login.jsp which is not the real path of the Login.jsp page !!

Comment: edited an answer.. but I guess you got the point that where it's getting wrong.. but if you're interested in the best practice to do this, then you can post another question because that will be out of the scope for this question :)